# HTTP GET : Header (Authorization : Bearer Token)

Tags: flutter, http, get, bearer-token

I am making a request in postman with the same URL mentioned below in the code and in the header passing accept and Authorization with bearer token.
In postman it is working completely fine and giving desired response but in flutter in my code it is giving 403-Forbidden Request its somehow not passing the token(i am assuming).

```
  Future<ApiResponse<String>> getCompanyList() {
    String token =
        " ";

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json", 
      HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $token",
    };
    final String API = "https://.............";
    return http.get(API,headers: headers).then((data) {
      if (data.statusCode == 200 ) {
        final jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

        return ApiResponse<String>(data: jsonData, error: false, errorMessage: "");
      }
      return ApiResponse<String>(error: true, errorMessage: data.statusCode.toString());
    }).catchError((_) => ApiResponse<String>(error: true, errorMessage: "An Error Occureddddd!!!"));
  }
}
```

This is my Service Class i am calling it from my Dart class anf it is calling fine.

```
class ApiResponse<T> {
  T data;
  bool error;
  String errorMessage;

  ApiResponse({this.data, this.error = false, this.errorMessage});
}
```

ApiResponse.dart

Comment: POST/GET request need an URI object not String object so you should use `http.post(Uri.parse(url), ...)`, and more help below

Comment: No i don't think this will be the case because at least it is giving response 403

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the headers as a map

something like this

```
var res = await http.post(url, body: body,headers: {
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Content-Type" : "application/json",
      "Authorization" : "Bearer $token"
    },);
```

Comment: With `"Authorization" : "Bearer $token",`

Comment: http.get(API, headers: {"Accept": "*/*", "Authorization": "Bearer $token"}) 

Added this still not working?

Comment: just see if it is the problem of the api just try to hit the url with the postman

Comment: so you can use dio as your package

Comment: not working with dio as well.
my token is of 350 characters does that causing any issue?

Comment: can you attach the console log here

Comment: I have found the mistake it's actually cookie issue,i have to pass cookie(contains JsessionId) to get200 Success.
But i don't want to pass it without it i am getting 403.
So how to do that?